# How to plot DataFrame with a grouped index using secondary Y

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, yaxis

I have a dataframe I sourced from the WHO using JSON like this

```
import requests                 
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas import read_html
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize   
import urllib2, json 
import html5lib

#Measles - Number of deaths of children < 5 by country & year
url = "http://apps.who.int/gho/athena/data/GHO/MORT_100.json?profile=simple&filter=COUNTRY:*;CHILDCAUSE:CH6"
response2 = urllib2.urlopen(url)
response_json2 = json.loads(response2.read())   
dfWHO2 = json_normalize(response_json2['fact'])
dfWHO2 = dfWHO2.loc[dfWHO2['dim.AGEGROUP']== '0-4 years']
WHOMeaslesChildhoodDeaths = dfWHO2.pivot('dim.COUNTRY','dim.YEAR','Value').astype(float)

#Measles First Dose Vaccination rate
url = "http://apps.who.int/gho/athena/data/GHO/WHS8_110.json?profile=simple&filter=COUNTRY:*"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
response_json = json.loads(response.read())
dfWHO1 = json_normalize(response_json['fact']).pivot('dim.COUNTRY','dim.YEAR','Value').astype(float)
WHOMeasles1stVaccRate = dfWHO1
WHOMeasles1stVaccRate = WHOMeasles1stVaccRate.loc[:,'2000':'2016']

#Combine Dataframes
WHOCombinedData = pd.concat([WHOMeasles1stVaccRate,WHOMeaslesChildhoodDeaths],axis=1,keys=['Rate','Deaths']).swaplevel(1,0,axis=1).sort_index(1)

#Transpose dataframes to get ready for Plotting
WHOData =  WHOCombinedData.transpose()
```

It looks like this:
[image: WHOData Dataframe]

```
    dim.COUNTRY Afghanistan Albania Algeria Andorra Angola
dim.YEAR                        
2000    Deaths  10580   2   1550    0   1536
        Rate    27      95  80      97  36
2001    Deaths  14120   0   1616    0   4643
        Rate    37      95  83      97  65
2002    Deaths  6891    0   1646    0   6061
        Rate    35      96  81      98  66
2003    Deaths  225     0   2567    0   2238
        Rate    39      93  84      96  52
2004    Deaths  367     0   38      0   36
        Rate    48      96  81      98  52
2005    Deaths  2042    0   32      0   432
        Rate    50      97  83      94  32
```

I want to plot each of the columns in individual plots with 2 lines, one for Deaths and one for Rate.

Because the scale is so different I need to plot one of them on a secondary Y axis

The 1st problem is I couldn't get the RATE on the second Y axis.

The next problem is that I would like to plot multiple charts at once - one of them for each column but I don't  know how to do that.  I did try to plot one at a time, not the best method but it almost works, But there are nearly 200 countries, so doing it a smarter way is pretty much necessary.

This is what I tried for a single chart:

```
ax = WHOData.loc[:,'Afghanistan':'Afghanistan'].unstack().plot(secondary_y='True' ,kind='line', stacked=True)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
plt.show()
```

And this is what I got as a result:

[image: Dataframe Chart]

I will be very grateful for any help

Comment: Please use text, not images, of datasets, in your questions. It makes reproducing your scenario much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over columns, plot and show like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


for country in df.columns: # Iterate over countries
    df[[country]].unstack().plot(); # Unstack deaths and rates, plot
    plt.show(); # Switch to new plot
```

Note the use of [`pyplot.show`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html).

**Edit**

To plot separately deaths and rates, you can use `subplot`:

```
for country in df.columns: # Iterate over countries
    country_df = df[[country]].unstack().plot(); # Unstack deaths and rates
    subplot(2, 1, 1);
    plot(country_df[['Deaths']]);
    subplot(2, 1, 2)
    plot(country_df[['Rates']]);
    plt.show(); # Switch to new plot
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for this Ami.  Very helpful.  I took your suggestion about making it easier - and provided a text table of the data frame & also the code to pull in the whole thing.

Comment: This works great for giving me a separate plot for each data column.  Do you have any idea on how to plot the "Deaths" & "Rate" on separate Y Axis?

Comment: @kiltannen See update. BTW, It would be easier if your dataset would be text and not an image.

Comment: This second looks very promising. BUT unfortunately I am getting this error:  NameError: name 'subplot' is not defined  Which seems really odd.  I am looking at matplotlib docs now...

Comment: Oh, it should be ‘plt.’ In front of all the plotting functions.

Comment: Thank you.  I just finished working that out - and tried it which is good.  I was just coming back to say that!  and also to say I now have a new error:  TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute "'__getitem__'"  This is on the 1st PLT.
PLOT line

Comment: Check the line immediately under the ‘for’ - I forgot before to erase the plot at the end of that line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168983/discussion-between-kiltannen-and-ami-tavory).

Answer (score 1):

Ami's first piece of code answers the second part of my question, how to get each country to display on a separate plot.  Unfortunately his second piece of code does not successfully give how to plot a second series on a secondary y axis.

With a bit of research here:
[Matplotlib - Plots with different scales](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html)

I was able to finally figure it out.  The first thing I had to do was separate Deaths & Rate effectively.  This was required because the Dataframe was a Multivariate with a Rate & a Death for each year - and multiple years for each country

After that I then needed to get matplotlib to provide a YAXIS for rate separately from deaths because the scale in many cases was vastly different

There may of course be a cleaner way to write the code, but here is a set of code that works:

```
for country in WHOData.columns: # Iterate over countries
    country_df = WHOData[[country]].unstack(); # Unstack deaths and rates
    deaths = country_df.iloc[:, country_df.columns.get_level_values(1)=='Deaths']
    rate = country_df.iloc[:, country_df.columns.get_level_values(1)=='Rate']
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    color = 'red'
    ax1.set_xlabel('Years')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Childhood (<4) Deaths by Measles', color=color)
    ax1.plot(deaths, color=color)
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

    color = 'blue'
    ax2.set_ylabel('Vaccination Rate 1st Dose', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
    ax2.plot(rate, color=color)
    ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

    fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
    plt.title(country)
    plt.show()
```

This is what it produces:

[image]